# Properly parse CSV file to JSON file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, papaparse, csvtoarray

I have a CSV file and I want to parse it using PapaParse.  How do I do this properly?

I have so far:

```
Papa.parse(fileInput, {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log(results.data);
        console.log(results.errors);
    }
});
```

However, is there a better way to do this?  Is this the proper way to get errors?  The documentation didn't emphasize download: true or anything so I was wondering if there are any experts on this subject here.

EDIT: Also, am I suppose to further parse the file with papacsv or do it in react.  For instance, if I have multiple arrays in my data file which have a similar name reference.  Should I initially somehow parse the file so it groups all those references together and how would I go about doing this?

For instance,

Date, Name , Win/Lose

I want to group all the winners together.  How do I do that?

Comment: What i understood from official doc that `download` is not needed and your code is fine. IMO

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using of Papa parse, is for remote `CSV`.

`download: true` is for downloading the remote file.

By using Papa parse, this is the only way of getting errors, data, meta with parse result object.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//If(header:true)
var data = [
 {
    "date": "8/12/2018",
  "name": "foo",
  "win/loose": "win"
 },
 {
    "date": "8/12/2018",
  "name": "foo",
  "win/loose": "loose"
 },
  {
    "date": "8/12/2018",
  "name": "foo1",
  "win/loose": "win"
 },
];
var winners = data.filter(d => d['win/loose'] == 'win');
console.log(winners);
//If you want to group winners and losers then:
var grouped = data.reduce(function(acc, co) {
  var key = co['win/loose'];
  if(!acc[key]) {
    acc[key] = [];
  }
  acc[key].push(co);
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(grouped);
```

This'll give you separate array of winners from extracted data.